# cgi-bin file on my personal website that I can't access or change

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, cgi-bin

I am in the process of learning web development, and creating my first website.  I purchases a domain, set up hosting, and uploaded a Craft cms to my website.  I then decided that I would prefer a different content management system.

This was likely the wrong approach, but I FTPed into my site and attempted to delete all of the files to start fresh.  When I did this, found that there was a cgi-bin folder that I did not have access to.  I can't see it's content, it's size, open it, change permissions, or delete it.

My site now throws a 404 error, stating the URL can't be found on the server.  I've deleted the Craft databases, I've attempted to install WordPress, nothing works and I'm not sure why or what to do.  I suspect it might be an htaccess/permissions issue, but I'm not sure.

Comment: You can safely ignore cgi-bin folder, you can see it is there for legacy reasons, in old days there used to be CGI scripts which needed to be placed there to run. It has nothing to do with your WordPress site. I suggest you contact your hosting company.

Comment: Okay, I'll do that.  Thanks so much for your time and thoughtful response, Mohsin.